# Android : create customer in magento via SOAP API

Tags: java, android, api, magento, soap

i  was trying to create customer in magento via SOAP API (customerCustomerCreate (SOAP V2)) in android app , but i get this error :

> SoapFault - faultcode: '100' faultstring: 'Customer email is required' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

i set email address with this code :

```
 request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerCustomerCreate");
        request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);

        SoapObject value = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "associativeEntity");
        value.addProperty("key", "in");
        value.addProperty("value", "xxxxx@xxxxx.com");

        SoapObject complexFilter = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                "complexFilter");
        complexFilter.addProperty("key", "email");
        complexFilter.addProperty("value", value);
                    SoapObject filterArray = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                "complexFilterArray");
        filterArray.addProperty("item", complexFilter);

        SoapObject filters = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "filters");
        filters.addProperty("complex_filter", filterArray);

        request.addProperty("filters", filters);

        env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
        result = env.getResponse();
```

Does anyone have any idea what is the wrong I am doing here?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

if you dose not get the answer till you can use this..

```
public void CreateNewCustomer(String email, String firstname, String lastname, String password) {


            try {
                env.dotNet = false;
                env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
                env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
                request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");
                request.addProperty("username", "+++++");
                request.addProperty("apiKey", "+++++");
                env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

               public static HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL)
                androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
                session = env.getResponse();
                sessionId = session.toString();

                Log.d("sessionId", sessionId.toString()); 

                Log.d("Create "," Creating......");
                request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"customerCustomerCreate");
                request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
//              request.addProperty("product", product_id);

                //-----use Kvm Serializable class to serialize the key value data-------

                CreateCustomerKVMserialize createcustomerkvm = new CreateCustomerKVMserialize();

                createcustomerkvm.Email = email;
                createcustomerkvm.Firstname = firstname;
                createcustomerkvm.Lastname = lastname;
                createcustomerkvm.Password = password;

                PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
                pi.setName("customerData");
                pi.setValue(createcustomerkvm);
                pi.setType(createcustomerkvm.getClass());
                request.addProperty(pi);

                env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                env.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "customerData",new CreateCustomerKVMserialize().getClass());

                androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
                Object customer_create = env.getResponse();
                Log.d("mainactivity "," "+customer_create.toString());


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

---------CreateCustomerKVMserialize class-----------

```
public class CreateCustomerKVMserialize implements KvmSerializable{

    public String Email;
    public String Firstname;
    public String Lastname;
    public String Password;
//    public String Websiteid;
//    public String Storeid;
//    public String Groupid;

    public CreateCustomerKVMserialize(){}

    public CreateCustomerKVMserialize(String email, String firstname, String lastname,String password) {

        Email = email;
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
        Password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch(arg0)
            {
            case 0:
                return Email;
            case 1:
                return Firstname;
            case 2:
                return Lastname;
            case 3:
                return Password;    

            }

            return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         switch(index)
            {
            case 0:
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                info.name = "email";
                break;
            case 1:
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                info.name = "firstname";
                break;
            case 2:
                 info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                 info.name = "lastname";
                break;
            case 3:
                 info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                 info.name = "password";
                break;
            default:break;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(index)
        {
        case 0:
            Email = value.toString();
            break;
        case 1:
            Firstname = value.toString();
            break;
        case 2:
            Lastname = value.toString();
            break;
        case 3:
            Password = value.toString();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Remees, it works perfectly, except that I had to specify WebsiteId, StoreId & GroupId, which you had commented out.

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675384/how-to-create-an-api-for-shipping-extension-to-work-in-android-app

Comment: @BabyinCoding , Sorry man, I worked this in a long before. Anyway i will take a look and let you know if anything positive.

Comment: @RemeesMSyde Thanks for your support.

Comment: @RemeesMSyde i posted new question, please check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720862/shipping-charges-are-not-saving-in-database-for-android-app

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerCustomerCreate");
                    request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);

                    SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerCustomerEntityToCreate");


                    customerEntity.addProperty("email", "abqpo@120.com");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("firstname", "firstname");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("lastname", "lastname");

                    request.addProperty("customerData", customerEntity);


                    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
                    Object result = env.getResponse();
                    String custId  = result.toString();
```

where **env** is **SoapSerializationEnvelope**.