# Shipping charges are not saving in Database for Android App

Tags: android, magento, soap

we are using 2 shipping method in our magento site.

1. Table rate shipping method
2. Custom shipping method  [ extension]

we are doing **Android** app for our magento site....

when we use default shipping methods [ example :  "**Table rate shipping method** " ,code : "tablerate_bestway" ] shipping charges are working fine in site and in andriod app.

when we use custom shipping method [ example : "**custom shipping method 1**" , code "ship_ship" ] shipping charges are working fine in site **but we are getting "0" as shipping charges in android app** Because in APP, **shipping charges are not saving in "sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate " table**

this is the problem. what we need to do so that shipping charges should work in andriod app when we use custom shipping method.

Comment: hi, what value should've returned instead of "0"?

Comment: its not creating any row itself....

Comment: what are the differences between your default shipping method and your custom shipping method? can you post the code?